# Automating configuration of Rabbitmq install on Windows EC2 instance startup

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmqctl

Process:
We're standing up an AWS Windows EC2 instance that runs the user-data script to process through configuration files for us automatically. 2 of those files install erlang and Rabbit, and configure rabbitmq respectively. This configuration includes enabling the management plugin and configuring 2 user accounts.

Issue:
The scripts are not executing the rabbitmq commands to install the management plugin or configure the users needed. The way the scripts are processed we aren't seeing any errors in the log that is generated. The scripts work as expected if we log into the server and run them manually.

Things tried or confirmed:

- the .erlang.cookie file is present in the user directory of the user running the scripts, and does match the cookie in the system32 folder.
- the commands are being executed as a "elevated" permissions
- We have tried putting the configuration steps all in the second script and having the system account launch a powershell instance as the domain admin (with the cookie in place) and execute the configuration script with no change.

What I'm expecting is that the scripts that are being run at startup properly install and configure erlang and rabbitmq without requiring a user to log into the server to execute any of the scripts.